# compile source code from github to apk format

Tags: android, github, sdk

hi i want to compile a source code to apk
it is called virtual app
here is the link to source:
https://github.com/asLody/VirtualApp
can someone help me?

thank you
PS

Comment: The folder layout for this app doesn't open from the root folder (VirtualApp). In the IDE: open the project from the inside folder, e.g. instead of `VirtualApp/`, open `VirtualApp/VirtualApp/`, then choose "Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s)". Or in command line use `$ cd VirtualApp/VirtualApp` and then `$ ./gradlew assembleDebug` or whichever target you want.

Comment: i already open them with Android Studio Now What?